# Using "by" or "through"

Tags: word-choice

In my master thesis power point presentation I have written:

> Attacks consist of sending HTTP requests *by*
>    - Tools
>    - The Hacktuator itself

What I want to say here is that the Hacktuator can perform Attacks by running tools (which will send http requests) or by constructing and sending http requests on its own.

Is *by* correct? Or I should use *through*?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perhaps you should try _with_.

Comment: Perhaps you should try *using*.

Comment: PowerPoint presentations are just visual cues. So long as it prompts you to deliver the lecture, it has done its job. Even “• attacks • tools • Hacktuator” would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hacktuator is involved in both forms of attack, so you've branched your statement too early. Try, perhaps:

> *Attacks consist of HTTP requests sent by The Hacktuator either directly or via tools.*

If you need bullet points for the slide:

> *Attacks consist of HTTP requests sent by The Hacktuator*
>       *-   directly*
>       *-   via tools*

Comment: Never branch your statement too early. That's how Whiteman speaks.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you instead use "with" or "using" as in the following examples:

> Attacks consist of sending HTTP requests with The Hacktuator itself.
>
> Attacks consist of sending HTTP requests using Tools.